# gdalwarp can't find libgrass_dgl or libgrass_vector files

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

Using `gdalwarp` I get the following errors:

> ERROR 1: libgrass_dgl.7.2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
>   ERROR 1: libgrass_vector.7.2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file

The full command line I'm using is: `gdalwarp f1.tif f2.tif -te -3.0 4.7 1.2 11.1`

I'm using a Kubuntu 17.04 platform.
If I look in folder `/usr/lib/grass72/lib` these files are present. But gdalwarp can't find them. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. Might be a bug in gdal configuration or something. To fix it, do this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/grass72/lib/libgrass_* /usr/lib/`

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Can you perhaps add a quick explanation of what this is doing and why it works?

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/libgrass_*': File exists`

Comment: @CoderGuy123, that means you have the files (or the symlinks) in the right place

Answer (score 1):

Within a shell session, you can use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to define more library paths.

If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set, then to this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/grass74/lib
```

If this works (e.g. using `gdalwarp` doesn't raise the errors), then you can make this configuration work permanently system-wide:

```
echo '/usr/lib/grass74/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgrass.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Yep, that would work as well. In fact your solution is probably the more proper one.